# About pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

```
select * from _table 
pivot (sum(_money) for _month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[8],[12])) as A
```

This my sql code. But if i have more rows this code not correct. I want to automatic add _month columns

```
in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[8],[12])
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PIVOT requires you to hard-code the column names. In order to reference columns dynamically with PIVOT, you must create a dynamic SQL statement, using a CURSOR to loop through and add the columns to your statement.

For what it's worth, I went through a period of using PIVOT for a while but I almost never, ever use them anymore - there is almost always a much cleaner implementation.